# Angular client - ng serve stuck building with no logs of any possible failure

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules, npm-install

I recently made some sweeping version changes to my Angular project and ended up with a project that doesn't build. When running ng serve, I get the following output:

```
collaborate-ui % ng serve
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active
```

Then never progresses. I can't seem to extract any further logs to indicate where the build is getting stuck. I have tried running with --verbose but still no luck.

I assume the issue is with incompatible versions but I'm dealing with a black box wrt deciphering which versions are compatible or not.

Details from running ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.3
Node: 13.13.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.3
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.3
@angular/cdk                      9.2.1
@angular/localize                 9.1.2
@angular/material                 9.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.3
@schematics/angular               9.1.3
@schematics/update                0.901.3
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Any help on debugging this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please try to delete the `node_modules` run `npm cache clean --force` and install the dependencies again with `npm install` and after that serve the app with `npm run start` (or with the specified serve command from the package.json)?
I don't see much possibility that this will help, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Tried this all before :) Unfortunately not a discrepancy in the cache

Comment: I have the same problem since today, no clue what is going on....

Comment: Facing similar issue. ng serve stuck at 10%.

Comment: @ArunitMazumdar did it work for you ?? facing same issue , stuck at 10%

Comment: @PinkiSharma Nope and not even sure why. Got no errors from ng-cli.